# Flagging off-topic questions for low-rep users

Tags: discussion, flags

(For those who can't view the deleted question, it was asked by someone wanting to make a career change to software development, and asked for ways/tips on how he could do so without programming work experience.)

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507002/career-transitioning-to-programming), which is very obviously off-topic, so I was going to flag it. However, at the flagging screen, I am at a loss of what to choose:

- It is not about general computing and software
- It has nothing to do with servers and networking
- It does not lack sufficient information
- It is not "a problem that can no longer be reproduced"
- It is not about finding a tool or resource

So what should I flag these questions as? I could of course flag them for moderator attention, but that seems to be a grand waste of the moderators' precious time. Can we just have a generic "off-topic" flag that says the following, without choosing from a list of specific reasons that does not cover all cases?

> This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope
>   defined in the help center.

**Edit**: The question seems to later have been closed as off-topic without a specific reason. Does this mean that lower-rep users cannot flag it as such, but high-rep users can vote to close? In that case, shouldn't there also be a flag option for this?

**Edit #2**: So after receiving some feedback, I've learnt that there is a 'Other' flag for users with >3000 rep. Previously, it would seem that this wasn't just for >3k users, as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185867/no-custom-off-topic-message-when-flagging-on-so). In that case, can the 'Other' flag be reintroduced for lower rep users?

This is not the first time I've encountered an off-topic question but failed to find an appropriate flag for it (and thus did not flag it). There is no reason to expect that low-rep users will start abusing the 'Other' flag if it were reintroduced, as all flags have to go into review anyway, and users with a high declined flag count will get banned from flagging (or so I've read). This [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185867/no-custom-off-topic-message-when-flagging-on-so#comment570477_185873) does a good job of explaining why that feature shouldn't have been removed for <3k users.

Comment: I can't view that question now it's deleted although guessing from the title "primarily opinion based" would be a fair bet. But when you flag it gets accepted even if it gets closed for another reason such as the custom ones you can use when you have enough rep to vote to close.

Comment: @PeterJ The question was about a hardware guy wanting to switch over to software development, and asked for ways/tips on how he could do so without programming work experience - if I recall correctly. I suppose I could flag it as primarily opinion based, but that doesn't really feel right :/ We should be able to flag as "off-topic" just as it is.

Comment: FWIW, I believe a more general version of this question may be applicable over at the workplace SE.

Comment: Why not just other?

Comment: @Liam He doesn't have the reputation to use other. It requires 3000 rep.

Comment: Close reason selection paralysis, a common problem these days.  The dialog is so broken then you can only pick weasel-words.  It doesn't actually matter what you pick, the question will get closed with "does not appear to be about programming" message anyway.  Which is actually what you want to say, you just can't say it.

Comment: [I asked the same question awhile back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227877/flag-declined-with-please-use-standard-close-votes-or-close-flags-how-do-i-p). The only answer suggested waiting for a 3k user to come along and toss a close vote at the question.

Comment: Does the system has the ability to move questions to other SE? If so that might be an alternative to close or delete.

Answer (score 6):

I'd go with **Primarily opinion-based**, or **other**, explaining how it's not directly related to programming.

In its simplest form, maybe something like:

> Other: the question is about career advice and is therefore off-topic for this site

Though, you might want to leave a comment to further explain the problem to the OP. In my experience, they often get a few constructive comments (and that is why opinion-based became a more valid option).

Sample comment:

> This question is off-topic for this site. See the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more info.

Also, if anyone's wondering *where* such a question should be asked, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110856) thread has some insights. The short answer is: maybe [workplace.stackexchange.com](http://workplace.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The OP cannot use other as it requires 3000 rep. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185867/no-custom-off-topic-message-when-flagging-on-so).

Comment: Ah. Well, for now I'd go with opinion-based + comment then. But that does open up the discussion for possibly giving < 3k rep users some default other-option, or something like that. Though, I'm not sure if this is a common problem (with the low frequency of such questions + the high frequency of good comments on such questions)

Comment: I didn't know about the other flag (obviously). After skimming through the meta.SE question shared by @Antony, I think [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185867/no-custom-off-topic-message-when-flagging-on-so#comment570477_185873) needs some more attention.

Comment: @JWLim +1. I partly agree. That massively downvoted answer does have a point though. But marshal-earners should definitely have the option. It's the auto-commenting that might not work well with low-rep users.