# Flagging "how do I start?" questions as a sub-1k user

Tags: discussion, flags, scope, close-reasons

As a user that hasn't reached 1k rep, how do I flag questions that go like "I want to do X task using language Y, how do I start?"

I can't find anything that fits. I want to say that it's off-topic, but none of the off-topic flags really seem to fit. An answer [to this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253799/flagging-off-topic-questions-for-low-rep-users) suggests flagging it as opinion-based, but that just seems like it would be contextually less appropriate.

Essentially, I feel that the question truly is off-topic (out of scope for SO) and that this is the primary (and perhaps only) reason to flag it, but I can't find a flag that fits my intention. What should I do?

Comment: _too broad_ seems the right reason.

Comment: ["Where to start?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308836/839601)

Comment: too broad, unclear, pob, or sometimes even off-site are appropriate. And if multiple work, you have to decide yourself which is most appropriate in the specific case, though don't get tied in knots over it.

Comment: I agree with "Too broad". How much info is necessary to just start doesn't have a clear boundary and any good answer will be too long. As an aside, if you are feeling particularly kind when you come across one of these questions that are, "How to get started with language Y?", you can leave a comment pointing out that the tag wiki (often) already answers that question.